# swift ios 8 change font title of section in a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, fonts

I would like to change the font type and font size of a section header in a table view controller.

My code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    header.textLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 38)!
}
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Futura font file must be there inside your project folder

Comment: this font is included. the cell text had this font,too

Comment: ok..then try the above code in `viewForHeaderInSection` method. And take a label for header text `var title = UILabel() title.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 38)! title.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()` and then `header.addSubview(title)`

Comment: all ok, the above code is correctly - i put the code in the wrong swift file -.-

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Swift 3**

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let headerView = UIView()
            headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

            let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width:
                tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
            headerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Verdana", size: 20)
            headerLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
            headerLabel.text = self.tableView(self.tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
            headerLabel.sizeToFit()
            headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

            return headerView
        }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }
```

Comment: This isn't working - can you explain the headerlabel text entry?

Comment: It's setting the text of the label to the section title of the table view. I'm using it in a Live app running Swift 3. Do you have the title set beforehand?

Comment: You need to make sure there is a height for the cell for some reason - which made it work

Comment: Great point, I do set the height as well. I added that to my answer above for future visitors.

Comment: The problem is you are setting the height of the label equal the height of the table in this line: let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width:                 tableView.bounds.size.width, height: tableView.bounds.size.height))

Answer (score 91):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
{
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 38)!
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
}
```

Comment: This solution appears to be even cleaner than the accepted answer and worked great for me in Swift 2.0.

Comment: An even cleaner version of this, would be if the `UITableViewHeaderFooterView had a function call inject(font: UIFont, textColor: UIColor)` and the view isn't forced unwrapped

Answer (score 38):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) 
{
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 11)
    header.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
}
```

Comment: `UITableViewHeaderFooterView.textLabel` is a read-only property. So `header.textlabel = title` won't work.

Answer (score 14):

**Updated for Swift 3**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    let header = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header?.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 12) // change it according to ur requirement
    header?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red // change it according to ur requirement
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I found the easiest way is to do the following in your View Controller or Table View Controller.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {

    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 14)


}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Simple working solution: (Swift 2.0)**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

            //Create label and autoresize it
            let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width, 2000))
            headerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 30)
            headerLabel.text = self.tableView(self.tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)
            headerLabel.sizeToFit()

            //Adding Label to existing headerView
            let headerView = UIView()
            headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

            return headerView
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
                let hView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width, 44))
                hView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                let hLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(15, 2, 30, 44))
                hLabel.font = UIFont(name: "YOUR_FONT_NAME", size: 30)
                hLabel.textColor = kiExtremeOrange
                hLabel.text = alphabets[section]
                hView.addSubview(hLabel)
                return hView
}
```

Note:**First import the font you want to use**

Answer (score 2):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, 
forSection section: Int) {
    let headerView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    headerView.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 14)
}
```

Comment: see @Atticus answer above!

Answer (score 1):

## Xamarin/`C#`

Based on Atticus' answer using `willDisplayHeaderView`:

```
public override void WillDisplayHeaderView(UITableView tableView, UIView headerView, nint section)
{
    var header = headerView as UITableViewHeaderFooterView;
    header.TextLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName("Futura", header.TextLabel.Font.PointSize);
}
```

Please note that Xamarin is a cross-platform development tool for building iOS Apps using the C# language. The code above is C# and will not work in Xcode. This answer is just for developers who use Xamarin but still want to achieve what the OP also wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There're several ways for you to archive your question by customizing the view in your storyboard, xib, tableViewCell, or you can write it by code.

After your customization completed, you can use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let yourHeader = .....

    return yourHeader
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated for Xcode 11, Swift 5**

The top voted answers didn't work for me, *here's what did*:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    /// Create the view.
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = .clear

    /// Create the label that goes inside the view.
    let headerLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 0, width: tableView.bounds.size.width, height: 30))
    headerLabel.font = UIFont(name: "myFont", size: 12)
    headerLabel.textColor = .white
    headerLabel.text = "myHeaderName"
    headerLabel.sizeToFit()

    /// Add label to the view.
    headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)

    /// Return view.
    return headerView
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    /// Return the same height as the height of the label in your header view.
    return 30
}
```