# Swift 4 UITableView Like Apple Music Search

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using `UITableViewController` and I am playing an having multiple sections to my `UITableViewController`, I am just curious how do I get headings like Apple Music Search, see screenshot below:

[image]

I am talking about the 'Recent' and 'Trending' headings, are those just the section headings or multiple tables?

Comment: Grouped table with section headers.

Comment: “Recent” and “Trending” are almost certainly the section headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use built-in iOS table view section headers. Place your titles in the collection/ array and display it as follows:

```
let titles = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3"]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return titles[Int]
}
```

Also, you need to define number of sections:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return titles.count
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that works, but how do I style them so they look like Apple Music Headings?

Comment: Do you mean to make it bold?

Comment: Bold, a bit bigger and background white.

Comment: @user979331. To make Bold and bigger. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42891875/7698092) Answer